# React Router - Routing not working with browser history

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react router for my SPA, since I saw hash routing is not good for production I decided to go with browser history. But changing it to browser history, the routing doesnt work. Is there anything that I am doing wrong? my package json has `"history": "^2.0.0", "react-router": "^2.5.1",`          `

```
            var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory;

            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={PreAuthPage}/>
                <Route path="/loggedIn" component={PostAuthPage}>
                    <Route path="/loggedIn/page1" component={Page1}/>
                    <Route path="/loggedIn/page2" component={Page2}/>
                </Route>
            </Router>`
```

This is what I have in my client side and on server side, I have

```
          `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"/app")));

          app.get('*', function (req, res) {
              res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/app', 'index.html'))
           })
```

`

What should I be doing to access http://localhost:8888/loggedIn,

I tried to add `app.get("/loggedIn",...)`, but there is no specific html page to redirect. I have added it as a component.

Comment: You shouldn't add anything else to the express router - all your get requests `*` should be going to your index html file. Also you should not include slashes `/` when using `path.join` it defeats the purpose of it. Also you don't need to start your react-router routes with a slash.

Comment: what if there is server side authentication, I will have to specify get requests for specific paths...right?

Comment: Personally I would either authenticate the user and show a loading spinner on the client, or I would make the app isomorphic so that the authentication is essentially server-side on the first loaded route (but you still write authentication in a normal clientside way with no special express routes). But yes if it's not isomorphic then that's messier, you would have to load index.html on successful auth, and have a separate unauthed.html file to redirect failed requests I think

Comment: FYI you don't need `history` in your `package.json`, that's what `react-router` is wrapping with [browserHistory](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/8707d05b00273590e4d054771b8ae7ae9ad312e3/modules/browserHistory.js)